# Angular 4.3+ : HttpClient generic

Tags: angular, typescript, generics

I'm getting a syntax error for specifying a generic type T as the return value of this method:

```
  private getResource<T>(resource: string, pagination?: string): T {
    this.updateSessionToken();
    const url = this.buildUrl(resource, pagination);
    this.http
      .get<T>(url, {headers: this.headers, observe: 'response'})
      .retry(3)
      .subscribe(
        (response) => {
          return response;
        },
        (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          return error;
        }
      );
  }
```

What would be the fix to avoid using the any or void as the following suggestion by tslint:

[image]

Comment: You did  return nothing at all

Comment: Care to elaborate please ? I thought that the return in  the subscribe part will do the trick ?

Comment: `http.get()` is an asynchronous call that returns a promise.  You can't convert that into synchronous code.  You can use `async` and `await` to use a "synchronous style", but it's still asynchronous underneath.  There's no `T` value to return from `getResource()`.  All it can do is return a `Promise<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you define a return value which is neither void nor any (which also allows returning void), you must return a value in any return path.
Your `getResource` function never returns any value, since it has no return statement.
The only places you define a return value is inside another nested lambda function, as the syntax `(arg1,arg2,...) => {...}` implies. Thus, writing a return statement inside the body of this nested function would NOT return a value for the outer function, as you probably tried to do. Furthermore, `http.get` function is asynchronous, which means that you send the request and go on with reading the function code, and not being blocked while waiting for a response, and since there is no next line for the function, you exit the function without returning any value.
It seems like your architecture might be wrong, because in asynchronous programming you should not expect an immediate response, and instead supply the consequent action as a success lambda (instead of returning the response, use it the way you would use it outside that function), and the same for a failure function.

I suggest you to read a bit more about the topic of asynchronous request because it is a primary principle in web development, and recommend you to read specifically about Observer (which works basically on the same concept of Promise) in Angular.